# Extract complete index from PDF book

Tags: python, perl, pdf, metadata, data-extraction

I have a PDF book which has a poor index, just with the main chapters' names. However, the book inside, have a lot of titles, subtitles, inside each chapter.
I am looking for a script (Bash, Perl, Python... whichever script) able to parse the entire book and provide an output with the detailed book schema. Something like:

*REAL POOR INDEX*

*1. Introduction*

*2. Which is this book for*

*3. Which is this book not for*
...

*DESIRED INDEX*

*1. Introduction*

*1.1. Some-text-here*

*1.1.1 Another-subtopic-here*

*1.1.1.1 Even-another-subtopic here*

*(and so forth)*

*2. Which is this book for*

*2.1. Some-text-here*

*2.1.1 Another-subtopic-here*

*2.1.1.1 Even-another-subtopic here*

*(and so forth)*

*3. Which is this book not for*

*3.1. Some-text-here*

*3.1.1 Another-subtopic-here*

*3.1.1.1 Even-another-subtopic here*

*(and so forth)*

I have tried several options without success: using Python: PyPDF2, PyMuPDF, ising Perl: PDF::Extract and others.

Any suggestion please, with a full real life successful example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a link to the PDF or an extract of the PDF? See also [PDF::API2](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::API2)

Comment: You should verify that PDF is not _scanned_ book. If the book consists of _images_ then not much to parse, and you can only add TOC for pages. But if the book is normal PDF book you could use trial software to add TOC.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file and extract the index with the following regex:

```
r'1..*3.1.1.1 The last title'
```

Where you should replace the last title with the last title that you want to include

Comment: Obviously you need to put the right number of the section to include it in the text.


you need also to turn on re.MULTILINE and re.DOT flags